# does "entail" here means "cause"? does "a change of name" put him to trouble?

Tags: meaning

does "entail" here means "cause"? does "a change of name" put him to trouble?

Had she
merely asked for it back there is little doubt that Home's delicate
feelings would have led him to return it, even though he had been put to
much trouble and expense over the matter, which had **entailed** a change
of his name to Home-Lyon, to meet the woman's desire that he should
be her adopted son.

Comment: In that context, "required" would be a better synonym. "Caused" sounds like natural processes, more than actions of persons.

Comment: The change of name was part of the trouble which 'the matter' had put him to. _Entail_ means _involve, make necessary_.